# Laravel: printing inside the JQUERY block the response (array of objects) obtained from the Controller

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

I am dynamically populating interdependent select lists country, region etc

I populate country alright, and I send the id of the country via jquery to the controller, this sends the id to the model and this returns me the regions corresponding to that country id. So now I send via json those pairs, id and region to the jquery code as a response to the call back function.

I can see in firebug that it returns correct json pairs corresponding to the id and region name, but the select lists is populated with these two words all over

object Object
obect  Object
etc
and this pairs actually correspond to id and name, id and name and so on.
It is doing that because I am not printing the syntax -> for objects properly, but I dont know how to write that inside a JQUERY code. I can do it in the blade page @foreach $x as $y etc, but not inside the jq. So that is basically the question. How do you print array of objects inside JQUERY when you get a json response from the Controller ?

This is the JQUERY CODE>

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#country").change(function (event) {
            alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
         var country = $(this).val();
          $url = '{{URL::route('crud')}}';
          $.post($url, {input:country},function(data){            
                 $('#regions').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                var option = $('<option/>', {'id':key, 'text':value});
                $('#regions').append(option);
                }); 

              });
          });
     });
```

This is the controller which gets the id from Jquery

```
public function getRegion()
    {

        $id = \Input::get('input');
        $regiones = Region::returnRegion($id);
        return \Response::json($regiones);
    }
```

And this is the Model

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Session;
use DB;
class Region extends Model{



    public static function returnRegion($id)
    {
     $regiones = DB::table('regions')
       ->select('id', 'nombre')
       ->where('id_idioma', '=', '3')
       ->where('id_pais', '=', $id)
       ->distinct()
       ->get(); 

     return $regiones;   


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance it looks like you're not telling jQuery that you're expecting JSON to be returned. After the success closure (function(data){}) you just need to add `, "JSON"` i.e.:

```
$.post($url, {input: country}, function (data) {
    $('#regions').empty();
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        var option = $('<option/>', {'id': key, 'text': value});
        $('#regions').append(option);
    });
}, "json"); //This bit
```

This will cause jQuery to convert the response from json.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Using `lists()` instead of `get()` will return an array of key pair values where as using `get()` would essentially nest that inside another array. So, if you we're going to stick with `get()` you would need to change you loop to something like:

```
$.each(data, function (row) {
    var option = $('<option/>', {'id': row.id, 'text': row.nombre});
    $('#regions').append(option);
});
```

Comment: hello, thank you. I added that, but so far no changes. I can see in firebug the correct display of response and json, but the select list only shows object object pairs

Comment: My bad! Try changing `"JSON"` to lowercase.

Comment: Try using `console.log(key, value);` inside `$.each()` and then using firebug to see what the values of `key` and `value` are.

Comment: The edit you posted using `list()` rather than `get()` got rejected so I'll add the gist of it to my answer incase anyone else comes along with a similar problem.

Comment: The above is meant to say `lists()`

Comment: But I think I could fix that, it would be a matter of putting all the code into a larger function and calling that function from the first jquery snippet.

Comment: If you do have any further issues regarding the functionality of the conditional selects you'll need to open a new question as it goes out of the scope of this one. :)

Comment: I posted the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726659/jquery-loading-interdependent-select-lists-code-finished-but-minor-tweak-needed/31733130#31733130