# JQUERY: loading interdependent select lists code finished but minor tweak needed

Tags: jquery, json

Country Region Town

I manually choose one value from the 1st select list. So the second select list gets populated alright

You would expect the third one automatically to be preloaded too, but that does not happen unless I move the 2nd select list and choose something.

FULL JQUERY CODE

```
<script>

     $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#country').change(cargarProvincias);
     $('#country').change(cargarCiudades);
     });

         function cargarProvincias() {        

          //  alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
         var country = $(this).val();
          $url = '{{URL::route('crud')}}';
          $.post($url, {input:country},function(data){
                $('#regions').empty();                                 
                $.each(data, function(key, value){               
                $('select#regions').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>')

                    });

              },"json");


    }

          function cargarCiudades(){

        $('#regions').change(function (event) {
           // alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
            var region = $('#regions').val();
          $url = '{{URL::route('region')}}';
          $.post($url, {input:region},function(data){            
                 $('#towns').empty();                 
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                var option = $('<option/>', {'id':key, 'text':value});
                $('#towns').append(option);
                }); 

              },"json");
          });

          }

    </script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function showCrud()
    {
       $country = Property::returnCountry();      
       return view('crud', compact('country')); 

    }

     public function getRegion()
    {

        $id = \Input::get('input');        
        $regiones = Region::returnRegion($id);
        return \Response::json($regiones);
    }

     public function getTown()
    {
        $id = \Input::get('input');        
        $towns = Town::returnTown($id);
        return \Response::json($towns);
    }
```

And well,  the Model is not important to put it here because it does bring up correct values. The issue is in the JQUERY code.

I have tried to make calls to the functions cargarProvincias(); and cargarCiudades(); but that blocks everything and nothing is shown.

Comment: This: `'{{URL::route('crud')}}'` should be throwing a syntax error within the console. I'm not sure if `crud` is a variable or a hardcoded string but either way it's incorrect. Possible fixes include `'{{URL::route(\'crud\')}}'`, `'{{URL::route("crud")}}'`, or `'{{URL::route(' + crud + ')}}' depending on if `crud` is a string (which can use escaped single quotes or double quotes) or whether it's a variable which will need to be computed into the string.

Comment: hi, no that is not the problem as it does load all values correctly. That is what is called a named route, if the route were not correct, nothing would be shown and nothing would be loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came across the answer. Credits go to The Alpha who posted a resembling solution.  So while I know there are other examples of interdependent select lists out there, they were too complicated for me. However, this one that I am going to post, even myself understand it, so this means, you will by all means.

This is the final solution:

```
<script>

     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     cargarProvincias();
     cargarCiudades();
     $('#country').change(cargarProvincias);
     $('#regions').change(cargarCiudades);


     });

         function cargarProvincias() {         

          //  alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
         var country = $('#country').val();

          $url = '{{URL::route('crud')}}';
          $.post($url, {input:country},function(data){
                $('#regions').empty();                 
                $.each(data, function(key, value){                 
                $('#regions').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>')});
                     cargarCiudades();          
              });
           }

          function cargarCiudades(){     

           // alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
            var region = $('#regions').val();
          $url = '{{URL::route('region')}}';
          $.post($url, {input:region},function(data){            
                 $('#towns').empty();                 
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                var option = $('<option/>', {'id':key, 'text':value});
                $('#towns').append(option);
                }); 

              });


          }



    </script>
```

Warm thanks to all those who tried to contribute, by hinting their best.